# Switch active class every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to switch active class automatic between div's every x seconds?
without stop? i mean infinite loop.

tried setInterval and addClass to progfill, no success, any solution?
thanks

```
    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progfill"></div>
</div> 
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progfill"></div>
</div>   
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progfill"></div>
</div>
```

i need to add 'active' class to progfill class, for example:

[image]

second iteration:

[image]

Comment: Which divs do you want to change. Can you show an example of 2 or 3 steps and what the HTML would be changed to?

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? Do you want to add class `active` to every `.progfill` every x seconds and after adding the class, is the class being removed from the previous element or not?

Comment: any tries you've did to fix on? there will be broad suggestions without clear achievement.

Comment: Please share the code snippet that you tried

Comment: sorry guys, added some pics. i mean every x second add the active class to progfill class, and goes on every x secont without stop

Comment: Vladimir Aleksić yes removed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at my solution. It uses recursive setTimeout which performs better then setInterval.

**See why recursive setTimeout is better here** --> https://develoger.com/settimeout-vs-setinterval-cff85142555b

Also with a little bit of changes you can get this to work with any function you want to repeat X number of times on each X seconds.

**See full pen code here** --> https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/ypMNaN

```
// Be able to: 
// 1. Define function that takes some arguments
// 2. Be ablle to call that function X number of time every X seconds
// 3. On each iteration that fun takes other param

const elmnt = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
const numberOfelmnt = document.querySelectorAll('.item').length;
const activeClass = 'active';

const repeat = (numberOfIterations, timeBetweenItereation, stuffToRepeat) => {
  let iterationCounter = 0;
  const repeater = () => {
    setTimeout( () => {
       stuffToRepeat(elmnt[iterationCounter], activeClass);
       iterationCounter++;
       if (numberOfIterations === iterationCounter) {
          iterationCounter = 0;
       };
       if (iterationCounter >= numberOfIterations) {
          return;
       };
       repeater(); 
    }, 1000 * timeBetweenItereation);
  };
  repeater();
};

const addClassToElmnt = (elmnt, className) => {
  let elmntWithClassToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  [...elmntWithClassToRemove].forEach((curentElmnt)=>{
    curentElmnt.classList.remove(className);
  });

  elmnt.classList.add(className);
};

repeat(numberOfelmnt, 1, addClassToElmnt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe:

```js
var x = 1;

function updateClass() {
  let a = $(".progfill.active");
  a.removeClass("active");
  a = a.parent().next(".progress");
  if (a.length == 0)
    a = $(".progress").first();
  a.find(".progfill").addClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    updateClass();
  }, x * 1000);
});
```

```css
.progfill {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progfill active"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progfill"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progfill"></div>
</div>
```

`x` represents the number of seconds between the change and you can adjust that.